# Angular 4 replace DOM element

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a question about DOM replacing with angular.
When i click on my button i passed $event.
My objective is replace the button childrens with another div with text.

Can you help me please?

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn LG_btn-grey animated" 
  (click)="onSubmitResendEmail(user.email, $event);sharedService.getCurrentURL()">
  <app-icons-renderer 
    [name]="'sendEmail'">
  </app-icons-renderer>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give your `button` a Template Variable. Then in your Class, access it using `@ViewChild`. Then use `Renderer2` to add children to it.

Here's an example of a Button that adds new Content inside it using this.

Component Class

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('myButton') myButton: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  clickHandler() {
    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('Some text in div');
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.myButton.nativeElement, div);
  }

}
```

Template

```
<button 
  #myButton
  type="button" 
  class="btn LG_btn-grey animated" 
  (click)="clickHandler()">
  <p>Some content</p>
</button>
```

### Alternative:

If you have some HTML in the form of a string that you want to set as the content of the button,

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('myButton') myButton: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  newContent = `<div>Some text in div</div>`;

  clickHandler() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.myButton.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', this.newContent);
  }

}
```

[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkydax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Hello i have try already your solution, But my element is on a ngFor while.
When i try to access the button with ViewChild i only can acces to the first button :(

Comment: I don't think you mentioned that in your question. Use `@ViewChildren` in that case.

Comment: You'll have to use a DumbDirective to get all the references of the buttons and do the needful with it.

Comment: I may be misreading something, but in your original solution, doesn't it never replace the content, but rather just keeps appending children to the button element?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have flag value that will tell you which element is visible,
something like:

```
<button>
  <app-icons-renderer [style.visibility]="isEmailSent ? 'hidden' : 'visible'" [name]="'sendEmail'">
  </app-icons-renderer>
  <app-icons-renderer [style.visibility]="isEmailSent ? 'visible' : 'hidden'" [name]="'sentEmail'">
  </app-icons-renderer>
</button>
```

You can change isEmailSent value with your Button click event.

Update:
Not sure if this will keep space occupied, better option could be to use

```
<app-icons-renderer *ngIf="isEmailSent"
<app-icons-renderer *ngIf="!isEmailSent"
```

Comment: Hello, i need to replace the app-icons-renderer element with a text after some state in a ajax request.
So i need to acces my element directly in the ts file.